# Using selectionArgs doesn't work in a query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use the following:

```
String dbquery = "Select * From stops where stopname LIKE '%?%' LIMIT 100";
String[] uinputarray = {uinput};
Cursor c = sDB.rawQuery(dbquery, uinputarray);
```

This consistently crashes.

Curiously, if I use the old test code of:

```
Cursor c = sDB.rawQuery("Select * From stops where stopname LIKE '%" + uinput + "%' LIMIT 100", null);
```

It works flawlessly.

I've been reading up on selectionArgs and I honestly can't see anything wrong with what I've done.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to append the % to the selectionArgs itself:

selectionArgs = new String[] { searchString + "%" };

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=?", selectionArgs);

Note: Accordingly % and _ in the searchString string still work as wildcards!

Comment: Thank you! So that's what I was doing wrong! It works great now.
I'd give you an upvote but it requires more reputation. (sorry)

Comment: if answer is correct you should mark this as correct answer .